# Special Gift :) To share

Tags: riddle, rhyme

A special gift to have :)

These days we all tag :D

For it can't be held by one ;)

Doesn't distinguishes between daughter or son :p

For it can't be purchased or auctioned :*

Cost something more than money :D

It prevails in all weathers whether it is winter or sunny <3

Time for a hint :

> For it neither eats nor breaths but can last a lifetime

Hint 2

> A ship for easy to board but difficult to maintain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the answer

> friendship. Guessed it from the hint.??

A special gift to have :)

> Self explanatory

These days we all tag :D

> This maybe for a trend on facebook where there are some images asking to tag your friend for different task like: tag your friend whose name start with A,B,C etc, Or tag your friend whose birthday is in xyz month.

Doesn't distinguishes between daughter or son :p

> A brother and sister can be good friends. (Maybe)

For it can't be purchased or auctioned :*

> We cant purchase or auction friendship.

Cost something more than money :D

> Well it costs our time,emotions,etc.

It prevails in all weathers whether it is winter or sunny <3

> A healthy friendship runs throught

Answer (score 5):

Is the answer:

> A *birth* or a birth*day*?

A special gift to have :)

> Many receive gifts on their birthday

These days we all tag :D

> The day of one's birth is "tagged" or labelled as your "birthday".

For it can't be held by one ;)

> Millions share the same birthday.

Doesn't distinguishes between daughter or son :p

> You often don't know whether you are having a son or a daughter until you give birth. Also the terms "birth" and "birthday" are gender neutral.

For it can't be purchased or auctioned :*
Cost something more than money :D

> Speaking of birth, life is precious and cannot be bought or sold. And your birthday is immutable - you can't sell it or change it.

It prevails in all weathers whether it is winter or sunny <3

> People are born all year round!

Comment: A good answer.. but not the one i had in my mind... there is more to it plus the answer itself is treated as a "gift" sometimes. Anyways +1 for creativity.

Answer (score 3):

Is it

> <s>murderous rage</s> EDIT: love?

A special gift to have :)

> not all people have experienced it firsthand

These days we all tag :D

> everybody feels that way about the ubiquitous hashtags

For it can't be held by one ;)

> the feeling needs to have an object other than yourself, otherwise it will be bad for you

Doesn't distinguishes between daughter or son :p

> I don't think it would, no.

For it can't be purchased or auctioned :*

> It has to come from the heart to be genuine

Cost something more than money :D

> You have to give yourself to it completely

It prevails in all weathers whether it is winter or sunny <3

> It is, indeed, a feeling that endures all

As an extra clue, the smileys at the end of each line are an excellent way to <s>instill</s> convey it in writing.

Comment: Quiet Close to the actual answer.

Answer (score 2):

Is it:

> A smile?

A special gift to have :)

> When someone smiles at you it's because something good has occurred. I've heard the phrase "Gifts you with a smile" plenty of times before.

These days we all tag :D

> Often when people text they tag it with smiley faces at the end of the line

For it can't be held by one ;)

> You can't physically hold a smile, also most people have the ability to smile

Doesn't distinguishes between daughter or son :p

> Any gender can smile

For it can't be purchased or auctioned :*

> You can't auction a smile off or buy it

Cost something more than money :D

> Many people say happiness is worth more than money, and happiness is what causes people to smile

It prevails in all weathers whether it is winter or sunny <3

> You can smile in any weather, and during dark or light times

The hint:

> It can be drawn/painted/photographed/written as an emote and it lasts a long time

and also

> All the emotes allude to it too